# Weird issue on sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I encountered this error when creating aggregate function 
This is the create script :

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY MyAgg FROM 'C:\AggregateConcatenate4.0.dll';
GO
CREATE AGGREGATE MyAgg (@input nvarchar(max)) RETURNS nvarchar(max)
EXTERNAL NAME MyAgg.Concatenate;
```

This is the error :

```
  Msg 6285, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
    CREATE ASSEMBLY failed because the source assembly is, according to MVID, identical to an assembly that is already registered under the name "AggConcat2".
```

But when I tried to drop the Aggregate using this script :

```
DROP AGGREGATE [dbo].AggConcat2;
```

I encountered this error :

```
Msg 3701, Level 11, State 5, Line 2
Cannot drop the aggregate function 'dbo.AggConcat2', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
```

I cannot figure out why and when I check on object explorer "Aggregate Functions" folder was empty.

**UPDATE**

Assemblies are present 
[image]

Get rid of error after dropping assemblies :

```
DROP ASSEMBLY MyAgg
```

Comment: Maybe `AggConcat2` isn't in the `dbo` schema?

Comment: Do you create with dbo?

Comment: yes, default schema is dbo sir @GiorgiNakeuri

Comment: CREATE *ASSEMBLY* and DROP *AGGREGATE* aren't opposite actions. The first error is telling you that an *assembly* named `AggConcat2` exists.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to specify my create script.

Comment: I tried the scripts in sql server 2008 and its working fine, i can even see the function in object explorer